# My addrow button in DataTables is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to create a button that can help me to add a row into a DataTables table and still remain every element in each column.

I don't know why my code didn't work.

```js
var table = null;
var arrData = [];
var arrDataPG = [];
arrData.push({
STT: 1,
id: 1,
product_type: "",
condition: "",
cashback: 0.0,
note: ""
 });
$('#addRow').on('click', function () {
    console.log(arrData.length);
    if (arrData != '') {
        var ida = arrData[0].id;
    } else {
        var ida = 1;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
        if (arrData[i].id > ida) {
            ida = arrData[i].id;
        }
    };
    arrData.push({
        STT: ida + 1,
        id: ida + 1,
        product_type: "",
        condition: "",
        cashback: 0.0,
        note: ""
    });
    if (table != null) {
        table.clear();
        table.rows.add(arrData).draw();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<table id="example" class="cell-border hover" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>STT</th>
                        <th>Loại sản phẩm*</th>
                        <th>Điều kiện áp dụng</th>
                        <th>Rebate(%)*</th>
                        <th>Ghi chú</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="sorting_1" style="width:50px">
                            1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <textarea class="form-control text-primary" style="width:300px;" id="product_type"></textarea>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <textarea class="form-control text-primary" style="width:300px;" id="condition"></textarea>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" id="cashback">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <textarea class="form-control text-primary" style="width:300px;" id="note"></textarea>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="btn btn-danger remove" id=""><i class="fa-solid fa-ban"></i></div>   
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            
            <button style="width: 86px;" id="addRow" class="btn btn-success add">Addrow<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "_my code didn't work_" - It is always helpful if you tell us exactly _how_ your code does not work - for example, by including any relevant error messages (as formatted text).

Comment: yes sir @andrewJames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to initialise the DataTable before you can add the data to it - once that's done, you need to tell it about the shape of your data. You're also running into an issue that the data you've got in `arrData` is overwriting your input fields - so I moved the inputs into the table footer; that seems to make the most sense, TBH.

```js
const arrData = [{
  STT: 1,
  id: 1,
  product_type: "Car",
  condition: "Poor",
  cashback: 20,
  note: "Well knackered"
}]


const table = $('#example').DataTable({
  data: arrData,
  columns: [{
      data: 'STT'
    },
    {
      data: 'product_type'
    },
    {
      data: 'condition'
    },
    {
      data: 'cashback'
    },
    {
      data: 'note'
    },
    {
      data: 'id',
      visible: false
    }
  ]
})

$('#addRow').on('click', function() {
    let ida = null
  if (arrData != '') {
    ida = arrData[0].id
  } else {
    ida = 1
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
    if (arrData[i].id > ida) {
      ida = arrData[i].id
    }
  }
  arrData.push({
    STT: ida + 1,
    id: ida + 1,
    product_type: $('#product_type').val(),
    condition: $('#condition').val(),
    cashback: $('#cashback').val(),
    note: $('#note').val(),
  })
  table.clear()
  table.rows.add(arrData).draw()
  $('#product_type').val('')
  $('#condition').val('')
  $('#cashback').val('')
  $('#note').val('')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js
<table id="example" class="cell-border hover" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>STT</th>
      <th>Loại sản phẩm*</th>
      <th>Điều kiện áp dụng</th>
      <th>Rebate(%)*</th>
      <th>Ghi chú</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td class="sorting_1" style="width:50px">
        1
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea class="form-control text-primary" style="width:300px;" id="product_type"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea class="form-control text-primary" style="width:300px;" id="condition"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" id="cashback">
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea class="form-control text-primary" style="width:300px;" id="note"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn btn-danger remove" id=""><i class="fa-solid fa-ban"></i></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<button style="width: 86px;" id="addRow" class="btn btn-success add">Addrow<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

Hopefully, that will get you on the right track. The thing to take the most notice of is your initialisation of the DataTable; once that's there, you should be fine.

Comment: can i ask you more about datatables  @annoyingmouse

Comment: There are a lot of people who use DataTables on here @quanhprx - if you make a reasonable stab at trying something, then most people will help. StackOverflow is generally a kind place and I can't guarantee that I'll always be about to help.

Comment: yes sir 
i think i will create another question